# sun.misc.Unsafe putInt, getInt source

Tags: java, unsafe

Please, tell me, where i can get source of methods `sun.misc.Unsafe#getInt(java.lang.Object, long)` and `sun.misc.Unsafe#putInt(java.lang.Object, long, int)`.

Or how replacement with using pure java types?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/misc/Unsafe.java

Comment: These methods is native, where are you seen them source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to find the source. The `Unsafe` is implemented by java and native source. So I found the two sources.:

- [OpenJDK8u Unsafe.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java)
- [OpenJDK8u unsafe.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp)

There is the **[header file.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp)**